# Remove from dictionary and reduce other key value

Tags: c#

I have `Dictionary<string, string>` where keys have value `0,1,2,3,4,etc` I always have unknown number of elements. It is important to be dictionary,not list etc...

For example I have

```
some_dict<"0","string a">;
some_dict<"1","string b">;
some_dict<"2","string c">;
some_dict<"3","string d">;
some_dict<"4","string e">;
```

Now I need remove some items for some keys. For example `1 and 2` I can use `remove`

```
some_dict.remove("1");
some_dict.remove("2");
```

and i get :

```
some_dict<"0","string a">;
some_dict<"3","string d">;
some_dict<"4","string e">;
```

But problem is that i need reduce all of the following keys.To get something like:

```
some_dict<"0","string a">;
some_dict<"1","string d">;
some_dict<"2","string e">;
```

I was think to use `for` to move all strings for one place,and then remove last from dictionary.For example i need to remove key 1:

```
for(int i=1;i<some_dict.count();++i)
{
     some_dict[Convert.ToString(i)] = some_dict[Convert.ToString(i+1)]
}
some_dict.remove(some_dict.count()-1);
```

I write some similar in my app , and it is work. But what if i have 500 or more values in dictionary, will be this slow? Can i use some better method?

Comment: Just don't use a dictionary. If the key simply contains an index number, why not use a List<T> ?

Comment: If you need it as dictionary, why don't you use a `Dictionary<int, string>`?

Comment: why dont you use Dictionary.ContainsKey, to find keys you want to remove?

Comment: The things you are doing to the dictionary look very much like emulating a list with a dictionary, which is naturally a lot of pain. Why is it "important to be dictionary,not list etc."?

Comment: This sounds like a case of the [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) - asking about the attempted solution, not the actual problem. What is the *actual* problem here? Are you trying to hold a list of strings in a user-defined order?

Comment: Thanx for answers and advice. I am still beginner and i need dictionary because i not work alone on this and other parts of program expect dictionary. This is only dictionary where i need to remove ,but i have about 20 dictionary's. I (was) think that changing whole code because this wold be mutch paint-full than this. I try solution from `Tim` and its work perfect. Thanx everybody :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you insist on your dictionary:

```
// remove whatever you want to remove, then recreate it:
some_dict = some_dict.OrderBy(kv => int.Parse(kv.Key))
    .Select((kv, index) => new { pair = kv, index })
    .ToDictionary(x => x.index.ToString(), x => x.pair.Value);
```

But as others commented you should consider to use a `List<string>` which can be used like a dictionary if you want to access items by index. You should also consider to use a `Dictionary<int, string>` if you want to use a dictionary.

Comment: Unless something has changed recently, iterating a dictionary offers no guarantee about the order.

Comment: @Rawling: now it is guaranteed

Comment: Do you have a spec link for that?

Comment: @Rawling: yes: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb549422(v=vs.100).aspx (you were right but i have edited my answer)

Comment: Aha, I see what you mean :)